# Compression/power increase for ethanol engine?

Tags: motorcycle, engine-theory, alternative-fuels

It's said that ethanol is capable of more power than gasoline in an engine exclusively designed for it. I believe this is because it can handle higher pressure before detonating, meaning higher compression ratio and\or more boost is possible.

My question is, what percentage of a power increase (roughly) would you get in a high compression **pure** ethanol engine? Specifically I'm asking about sport bike style engines (around 15,000+ rpm naturally aspirated).

Also what would the compression ratio be roughly, and does power just increase in proportion to the compression ratio?

Answer (score 4):

There's a very handy formula for computing the effective power output of an internal combustion engine:

```
Effective power =   engine displacement
                  × effective working pressure
                  × engine speed
                ( × unit conversions )
                ( ÷ 2 [ if engine is 4-stroke ] )
```

The upshot of this formula is that **it doesn't matter what fuel is being used** - the power output is influenced by an engine's displacement, speed and effective working pressure.

For the purposes of this question, the impact of gasoline vs ethanol will be felt as a change in effective working pressure.

As an example (since I don't have actual data):

> If ethanol safely supports a 15:1 CR in a naturally-aspirated application where gasoline can only go up to 10:1 before detonation becomes a concern, one can expect the effective working pressure to improve by up to 50% (of course, the engine's compression ratio will physically have to be altered to take advantage of ethanol).
>
> If all else remains constant, this would translate to an effective power output increase of 50%

Comment: Well, my way of setting up the calculation may have been flawed, but it looks like the answer was close.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found some information from [AmericanEnergyIndependence.com](http://www.americanenergyindependence.com/alcoholengines.aspx):

> Because of the compression limitation required to prevent “engine knock”, a typical gasoline engine can only deliver about 25% efficiency — only 25% of the BTU's in a gallon of gasoline are converted to mechanical energy that turns the wheels of the car, the other 75% is lost in waste heat.
>
> An Alcohol Engine can deliver about 40% efficiency — 40% of the BTU's in a gallon of ethanol powering an Alcohol Engine will produce mechanical energy that turns the wheels of the car.

<sub>*Note that efficiency refers not to fuel efficiency, but to efficiency per BTU.</sub>

Some math:

```
0.40 / 0.25 = 1.6
```

In other words, the amount of power you can gain from the same BTU's would be **aproximately 1.6 times greater.**

Courtesy of Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: Note that you also have to put in more fuel to get the same number of BTU's.  (Pure ethanol has an energy content of 84,530 BTU/gal, whereas standard gasoline has around 120,388 BTU/gal.)

This means that you get approximately the same power *per gallon*, but because the Ethanol supports a higher compression ratio, you can send more gallons through the engine.  The end result is that you get the same amount of power *per gallon,* but you get a 60% increase in your power *per minute.*

Comment: You didn't take into account the energy density of the different fuels.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, good point, I'm working on something there.

Comment: So ethanol has only (roughly) 2/3 as much energy, but is 60% more efficient in an internal combustion engine. This means it's somewhere around 107% as efficient overall. But I'm not sure about power.

Comment: @Guest, you're absolutely right.  I'm trying to iron this out, but if I can't, I'll simply delete the answer.  It looked like the American Energy Independence thing was on to something, but it appears they might not actually be taking the power into consideration.

Comment: Actually aren't the power and efficiency improvements the same here, because raising compression increases power for the same amount of fuel. Like turbos being more powerful and fuel efficient I believe (more cylinder pressure).

Comment: You can expect ~3% power increase per point of compression, all other things being equal. At least that's the rule of thumb for a naturally aspirated engine.

Comment: Actually, the Atkinson-cycle gasoline engine in a Toyota hybrid can deliver 38% efficiency, pretty close to the stated 40% efficiency of an ideal ethanol engine. An ethanol Atkinson-cycle engine would obviously have a lot higher efficiency. In freeway cruising, the Atkinson engine is operating close to its ideal operating point, and in city driving the engine is toggled on/off (when on, charge the battery at the ideal operating point; when off, drive using the traction battery). A typical non-Atkinson cycle engine in a non-hybrid is about 25% efficiency, though.

Comment: Food for thought: thermodynamic efficiency won't tell you how *much* fuel will be consumed in the process of supporting a certain power requirement.